# Array from array's string

Tags: arrays, json, string

I have an array of JSON objects, for example,

`arr = ["{"topic":"none","url":"https://google.com"}"]`
also, I have the string of this array. How can I convert the string back to an array?
I tried to use JSON.parse(), but it doesn't work:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 4
```

Comment: What language do you want to do this in?

Comment: Your objects inside your array are strings. Do you want these to remain as strings? Or are you trying to convert the array you have given us (an array of strings) to an array of objects?

Comment: I think you confuse between the `"` char - wrap your object with `'` and keep the `"` for inner object strings

Comment: Make sure you build JSON with corresponding functions. Trying to make JSON by hand is not the way to go. What you provided is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I made a tiny bit change to your array to make it a valid string.

```
arr = ['{"topic":"none","url":"https://google.com"}']
```

Try this. You can always call JSON.parse() with a VALID Json string as a parameter to get back an object.

```
arr = [JSON.parse(arr[0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you set array as object array like as below,

```
arr = [{"topic":"none","url":"https://google.com"}];
```

Try this code,

```
arr = Objects.entries(arr);
```

any issue inform me.